# How to execute tern for vim commands?

Tags: javascript, vim, tern

I am new to Vim and  installed tern for vim:
https://github.com/ternjs/tern_for_vim

I would like to use the command `TernDef` to jump to the definition of a function.

I tried to put the cursor on a function name and enter `:TernDef` but that does not work:

```
E492: Kein Editorbefehl :TernDef
```

Does "command" mean something different than the ":"-commands?

Key shortcuts for tern_for_vim can be enabled with:

```
"enable keyboard shortcuts
let g:tern_map_keys=1
```

Source: http://www.dotnetsurfers.com/blog/2016/02/08/using-vim-as-a-javascript-ide/

The article above does not tell me which key shortcuts are mapped to the tern commands. How can I find out?

I use gVim 8.1 on Windows7 and cloned the tern_for_vim plugin to

C:\Users\eis\vimfiles\pack\mypackages\start\tern_for_vim

Furthermore, I set the windows system environment variable HOME to C:\users\eis

Related question:
[How to setup tern-vim in my project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41541755/how-to-setup-tern-vim-in-my-project)

Comment: https://github.com/ternjs/tern_for_vim/blob/3cffc28f280fc599d3f997b1c8c00ddc78d8fc21/doc/tern.txt#L127-L141 Here's the documentation for the key bindings.

Comment: So it should be "\td" ? Does not work. (at least not with German keyboard)

Comment: If the `:TernDef` command is not defined, then the tern plugin wasn't loaded.

Comment: if I execute :scriptnames, the tern.vim file is included in the list. Therefore, I assumed that it would have been loaded. How can I check if it has been loaded correctly?

Comment: Which tern.vim? I see two of them in the repository.

Comment: The relevant file to enable everything seems to be https://github.com/ternjs/tern_for_vim/blob/master/after/ftplugin/javascript_tern.vim, which is a filetype plugin for javascript.

Comment: The shown path is c:\users\eis\vimfiles\pack\mypackages\start\tern_for_vim\ftdetect\tern.vim   Why should the file in "tern_for_vim/after" be used in your opinion?

Comment: Look at [ftdetect/tern.vim](https://github.com/ternjs/tern_for_vim/blob/master/ftdetect/tern.vim). All it does is set the file type of tern config files to "JSON". javascript_tern.vim contains `tern#Enable()`, which is what bootstraps the whole thing.